# ServiceStack how to strip all HTML tags in Response

Tags: servicestack

I need simple thing - Strip or encode all HTML tags in service answers. What I need to write?
I have many services, so by default (without attribute) - Replace Tags,  if I have custom attribute - dont replace.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There's an `string.StripHtml()` extension method in ServiceStack.Text that allows you to strip html tags with:

```
var text = html.StripHtml();
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need attribute or filter for all services, all text fields.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to strip all text fields by default? In which case you would need to use reflection iterating all properties in a Request filter.